# Porque al poner matriz[0].length imprime un 2 en pantalla?

Tags: java

Al imprimir esto me sale un 2 por pantalla

```
int matriz[][]=new int[3][2];
System.out.println(matriz[0].length);
```

Comment: Por que el length de tu matriz[0] es 2(tamaño horizontal), cual es el problema?

Comment: Primero debes de conocer que es lo que hace el método `.length`

Answer (score 2):

Tu array bidimensional fue declarado de esta forma:

```
new int[3][2];
```

3 renglones y 2 colummas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

al requerir la longitud de tu array mediante `.length`, obtienes la longitud del array ("horizontal") que serían 2 elementos (columnas), por esta razón obtienes el valor de `2`.